# Use Query and filter But "No Column: Col15" error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a master data with 20 columns. I use `query()` to extract data but it says : no column: Col15 error

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("15EKBUMLhbpHL-bzOTEF2mtYVbuC4sHWtZrPJqynedJ0";"'BANHANGT8.19'!A3:N")};"select Col1, Col2, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col14, Col15";0)
```

I expect Col15 should be shown up: Col15 is stored as plain text although it has number and text: 331-hoàng an

Comment: Since you're importing columns A:N, and N being the 14th letter in the alphabet, I guess you indeed don't have a column 15 in your range...

Comment: OMG, thank you very much, i'm sooo sillyyyy. You've made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably easily fixed with

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("15EKBUMLhbpHL-bzOTEF2mtYVbuC4sHWtZrPJqynedJ0";"'BANHANGT8.19'!A3:T")};"select Col1, Col2, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col14, Col15";0)
```

to actually import the first 20 columns. Cfr comment in original post.